# Automate downloading images off Google

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, urllib2

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to create a tool that automates downloading images off Google.

So far, I have the following code:

```
import urllib

def google_image(x):
    search = x.split()
    search = '%20'.join(map(str, search))
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=%s&safe=off' %
```

But I'm not sure where to continue or if I'm even on the right track. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

see scrapy documentation for [image pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html)

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

Comment: So I have to install Scrapy but then what?

Comment: by the tags of your questions I thought you already did, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. Relatively new to Python and programming as a whole, and I'm trying to write the code to download the images of a certain search off Google.

Comment: you'll have to download and install scrapy and maybe go over scrapy tutorial to understand how to build a spider http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Scrapy?

Comment: Preferably I'm just trying to recycle code, not necessarily developing my own. All of the code I'm trying doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. Do you have any ideas? I just need a quick batch of code to do what I want it to do.