# Automate downloading images from Google Images

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I want to download images of Star Wars episode 7 Force Awakens wallpapers.

Based on [Automate downloading images off Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318393/automate-downloading-images-off-google)

```
import urllib

def google_image(star wars force awakens wallpaper):
search = x.split()
search = 'star wars force awakens wallpaper'.join(map(str, search))
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=%s&safe=off' % 
wget $imagelink
```

I don't know how to run this, I am new to bash files?

EDIT: how do I check what the image saves as to automate the sorting?

If relevant the sorts of pictures are like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=star+wars+force+awakens&biw=1280&bih=905&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiNqq3tpOjJAhWC6yYKHbPHDRIQ_AUICCgD#tbm=isch&q=star+wars+force+awakens+wallpaper

Comment: Basically, you want command line version of firefox's [flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) addon?

Comment: @anishsane exactly, only I want to do it with bash since I use Chrome, and to learn bash files.